# permission_classes preventing Android app from accessing DRF?

Tags: android, django, rest, authentication

I am having trouble developing a Android app that I want to authenticate with Django REST framework to securely access information. I am being successfully issued a REST token but `IsAuthenticated` remains false for all of my views.

In Django, I have a class based view that responds if both `authentication.TokenAuthentication` `permissions.IsAuthenticated` are valid:

```
class TestAuthView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return GetRestData()
```

In Android, I acquire a token by POSTing my **uname** and **passwd** to the default url: `/rest-auth/login/`which responds with token: `{"key":"c03c1238ab99d91301d34567bda9d417d2b48c0c"}`

```
public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(String... params) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,String>> paramssss = new ArrayList<>();

    paramssss.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("username", "root"));
    paramssss.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("password", "mypass"));

    URL url = new URL(params[0]);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getQuery(paramssss));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    urlConnection.connect();

    try {
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

        boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
        if (hasInput) {
            return scanner.next(); //eg. {"key":"c03c1238ab99d91301d34567bda9d417d2b48c0c"}
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I then store the token and later use it to request some data:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);

        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        String authToken = "c03c1238ab99d91301d34567bda9d417d2b48c0c"; //just use a constant string for now..
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + authToken);
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

        urlConnection.connect();

        ...
        process the response
        ...
```

Looking at the Django logs I see that login succeeds but the GET request fails with `HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED`:

> [08/Oct/2019 22:18:53] "POST /rest-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 50
>
> [08/Oct/2019 22:18:53] "GET /update/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58

When I change the permission_classes to `AllowAny`:

```
class TestAuthView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,) //Changed this!!!

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return GetRestData()
```

The response contains the expected REST data and everything succeeds:

> [08/Oct/2019 22:24:57] "POST /rest-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 50
>
> [08/Oct/2019 22:25:02] "GET /update/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19451876

I don't understand how I should properly authenticate my Android app so that `IsAuthenticated` will not always be False?

Currently I submit a username and password to `/rest-auth/login/` and am issued a rest token. But must I also login somewhere else to get a CSRF token and use that as well?

I am not familiar with the need for `permissions.IsAuthenticated` and if it is even valid for Android apps? I mean do I just leave the permission as `AllowAny` for non-browser Android apps? I feel it's a bad idea..?

I've been plugging at this for a few days and would kindly appreciate any help!

Comment: Try to comment out the `content-type` line while making get request. or set it to `application/json`

Comment: haven't difference between android app, postman or browser. Django get a request and if permission be `permission_classes=(IsAuthenticate,) ` expected token. so I think your wrong by sending token. for find what is going on, set permission to allow any and print `request.user` into your view. if not printed success then you are sending request wrong way and try @Satendra notice.